# Data storage as VARCHAR vs INT, "translation" server-side vs client-side

Tags: encoding, client-side, server-side

I'm struggling a bit with the best way to store data - "raw" data directly from the user vs "coded" data that needs translation. Here is a specific example of a select list indicating where a patient's blood pressure was measured:

```
<select id="location">
<option value="1">Office</option>
<option value="2">Home</option>
<option value="3">Hospital</option>
<option value="4">Work</option>
<option value="5">Other</option>
</select>
```

In the past, I would have made the storage variable VARCHAR and just stored it as all lower case "office", "home", "hospital", "work", "other". But over the last month I've been thinking that perhaps a more "elegant" approach would be to store it as an integer "code" (as in the example above) and then translate it when it is read from the table, like this server-side translation:

```
  $location=$row['location'];
  if ($location == '1') {$location = "Office";}
  else if ($location == '2') {$location = "Home";}
  else if ($location == '3') {$location = "Hospital";}
  else if ($location == '4') {$location = "Work";}  
  else if ($location == '5') {$location = "Other";}
```

So my noob questions to you are a bit philosophical -

1. Do you ALWAYS/SOMETIMES store data as "raw" VARCHAR data, or do you "code" in with integers/Boolean etc? Do you have criteria for doing either?
2. If you do "code" your data, do you "decode" it server-side or client side?

I thank you in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: **[magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) are bad.** You should under no circumstances use `if ($foo == 4)` in your code, because, to put it succinctly, **WTF does "4" mean?**

If at all, use constants for this purpose:

```
define('HOSPITAL', 4);

if ($foo == HOSPITAL) ...
```

That's not half bad, because you don't get in direct contact with the underlying meaningless value anymore. If you ever have to debug the application though, you will see that value everywhere, including the database. ENUMs are useful here, but PHP doesn't support them. The database does though. A compromise therefore is to use [ENUMs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) in the database and constants in PHP:

```
CREATE TABLE foos (
    foo ENUM('hospital', 'office', ...)
);

define('HOSPITAL', 'hospital');

if ($foo == HOSPITAL) ...
```

This gives you:

- type safety and reduced storage in the database
- type safety and minimally more efficient processing in PHP
- full clarity when writing and debugging code

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooooh...the light just went off!!! I assumed that the storage of a single integer would be more efficient, but based on your first comment, I guess not. So fortunately, I have only 6 "magic numbers" on my page that I can change to enumerated types. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! "magic numbers are bad" "magic numbers are bad" "magic numbers are bad" "magic numbers are bad" "magic numbers are bad" - :-)